# Cannot figure out why Unity is not injecting Identity DbContext properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, unity-container, asp.net-identity

I am new to Unity, and Identity, and I have restructured my implementation of Identity 2 to use int Keys instead of strings. I followed [this article](http://typecastexception.com/post/2014/07/13/ASPNET-Identity-20-Extending-Identity-Models-and-Using-Integer-Keys-Instead-of-Strings.aspx). It works great at this point. However, I am using Unity for IoC, and it works wonderfully with my repositories, however, I am struggling getting it to work with the Identity side. I followed [this article](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/09/aspnet-identity-and-ioc-container-registration/) to switch.

I have seen questions similar to this, but all of them were using string Keys, so I assume I have something funky somewhere since I am using int.

The issue is in the ctor of the `ApplicationUserStore` class:

```
public class ApplicationUserStore :
    UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int,
    ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole,
    ApplicationUserClaim>, IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>,
    IDisposable
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(IdentityDb context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

Here is the `IdentityDb.cs`:

```
public class IdentityDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int,
    ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public IdentityDb()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    static IdentityDb()
    {
        // Set the database initializer which is run once during application start
        // This seeds the database with admin user credentials and admin role
        Database.SetInitializer<IdentityDb>(new IdentityDbInitializer()); 
    }

    public static IdentityDb Create()
    {
        return new IdentityDb();
    }
}
```

And here is the relevant portion of `UnityConfig.cs`:

```
container.RegisterType<IdentityDb>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>();
container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();
container.RegisterType<ApplicationRoleManager>();
container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(
     new InjectionFactory(c=>HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>, ApplicationUserStore>(
     new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IdentityDb)));
```

When I attempt to run the app, the `context` parameter in the ctor of `ApplicationUserStore` is `null`.

I would appreciate any help that could be offered.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an exception while resolving `UserManager`. But MVC's Dependency resolver swallows it and return null instead of object.

In the `Startup.Auth.cs` instead of

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => 
     DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>());
```

write:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => 
     UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>());
//Don't forget to add Microsoft.Practices.Unity namespace
```

This cause your program fails when Unity could not resolve object and throws an exception. By reading details of the exception you could find the issue. If you need future help simply submit the exception too.

Comment: Thank you. When I try your suggestion I get:
`Error: 'Owin.IAppBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'CreatePerOwinContext' and the best extension method overload 'Owin.AppBuilderExtensions.CreatePerOwinContext<T>(Owin.IAppBuilder, System.Func<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryOptions<T>, Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext, T>)' has some invalid arguments`

This is the edited line that is giving me this error: `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>());`

Comment: It seems you edited code in wrong way. Try this not yours: `app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(() => 
     UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>());`

Comment: You omitted `()=>` actually.

Comment: I am sorry. When I originally typed it with the `()=>` I was receiving an error. Apparently I had a typo because now this issue seems to be solved. Thank you!